# Google Maps API v3 & AJAX - Removing markers

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I'm trying to allow users to click on a button and for a set of markers to come up showing a route (not gotten to polylines yet). I've got that bit working but what I'd like is to get it so that it deletes the previous markers before adding the new ones.

I've tried a lot of methods but I cannot seem to get any to work for me. I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong or theres some error in my code I'm not seeing.

I've looked [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove) to see if I could find a solution but again, nothing.

I'm sure the solution is incredibly simple. Any help would be appreciated.

The code:

```
var route = [];
var markers = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialise(){
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),{
        center: {lat: 37.7833, lng:-122.4167},
        zoom: 10
    });

    $('.route_button input').click(function() {
        clearMarkers();
        markers = [];
        $.ajax({
            url: 'include/routeinfo_ajax.php',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'xml',
            data: {'route': $(this).attr('name')},
            success: function(response) {
                setMarkerDetails(response);
                for(var i = 0; i<route.length;i++){
                    placeMarkers(map, route[i]);
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                console.log("error");
            }
        })
    });
}

function placeMarkers(map, route){
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(route[2], route[3]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:latLng,
        map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
      infowindow.close();
      infowindow.setContent(route[0]);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}

function clearMarkers() {
    for(var i=0; i<markers.length; i++){
        markers[i].setMap(null);   
    }
    markers = null;//Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null
    //when changed to markers = []; markers flash as if theyve been removed but both sets of markers are now in place, the previous are not removed

}

function setMarkerDetails(data){
    var stations = data.getElementsByTagName('stations')[0].getElementsByTagName('station');
    for(var i = 0; i<stations.length;i++){
        route.push([
            stations[i].getElementsByTagName('name')[0].innerHTML,
            stations[i].getElementsByTagName('abbr')[0].innerHTML,
            stations[i].getElementsByTagName('lat')[0].innerHTML,
            stations[i].getElementsByTagName('lng')[0].innerHTML,
            stations[i].getElementsByTagName('address')[0].innerHTML,
            stations[i].getElementsByTagName('city')[0].innerHTML,
            stations[i].getElementsByTagName('zipcode')[0].innerHTML
        ]);
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise);
```

Thank-you!

Edit: issue persists, and in firefox too so its not a browser issue. (Using chrome)

Comment: Looping through the markers and calling `setMap(null)` removes them (setting `markers = []` is a good idea as well). If they show up again after, it's because they're being returned in your AJAX response.

Comment: Just as an aside, you've declared a global `map`, but you never use it - did you mean to use the `var` keyword in your initialize function in front of `map`?

Comment: I'm not seeing a global map anywhere? There's the variable map at the start, was an overflow from a previous solution. Unless thats what you mean in which case yeah its not meant to be there. On the first response they are still showing up so I guess ajax is stil returning them. I'm not quite sure how to rectify this though

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the global `map` at the top of the code that you posted. You should examine your AJAX response to see what's actually being returned to your code.

Comment: Well all thats being returned is the xml data for each specific route as requested, I cant see anything untoward there. Hmm

Comment: FIXED IT I forgot to reset the route array so everything was accumulating in there. 6 hours spent looking and finally found the reason. YAY! Thanks for the help Adam

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line:

```
markers = null;
```

from your for loop and it should work. Also you don't need to pass the `map` variable to your function as you are not using it and it is defined in the global scope anyway.

```
function clearMarkers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }

    markers = [];
}
```

Comment: Won't the `markers` array just grow and grow if you don't also use `markers = [];`?

Comment: Yes, that's true. You need to reset your markers array at some point. I have edited my answer. It doesn't **have to** be in that function though...

Answer (score -3):

As I do, just call `initialize()` function. This should reset your markers.

Comment: ....And also redraw your map unnecessarily, and assign multiple click handlers, and do other bad things.